# Will two very closely related questions be downvoted for "rep-gaming"?

Tags: discussion

I have recently asked a question about the benefits of graduate students joining unions: [What are the benefits/detriments to graduate students joining unions?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20531/what-are-the-benefits-to-graduate-students-joining-unions)

I also want to ask a question about the drawbacks thereof, but according to this meta thread: [Multiple questions in one thread](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/960/multiple-questions-in-one-thread) I should ask a new question. However, the new post will largely be a copy-paste of the first one, and I do not want to seem like I'm just doing it for the rep. Should I edit my first post to have two questions, or put up a new post?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Asking about benefits and drawbacks are two parts of the same question. You should ask for both in the same post.

Comment: +1. "What are the benefits and drawbacks of graduate students joining a union?" can be rendered as a single question.